# How to stream docker container output to terminal when using Docker SDK for python

Tags: python, bash, shell, docker, stdout

I have a docker container that performs a set of operations and prints output to the terminal. I cannot figure out how to get the terminal output when using the Docker SDK for python.

Here is a example of what I want to achieve. Let's say that I have a folder containing the following files:

```
Project
  Dockerfile
  now.py
  dockerpy.py
```

where `now.py` is a simple script that prints the current time every second for ten seconds:

```
# now.py

from datetime import datetime
import time

for _ in range(10):
    print(datetime.now())
    time.sleep(1)
```

And the `Dockerfile` builds an image for a container that runs the script:

```
FROM python
ADD . /code
ENTRYPOINT ["python", "/code/now.py"]
```

Once I build the image with `docker build -t dpytest .`, I run `dockerpy.py` to start the container:

```
# dockerpy.py

import docker
from datetime import datetime

if __name__ == '__main__':

    client = docker.from_env()
    print('{} - Starting\n'.format(datetime.now()))
    container = client.containers.run("dpytest", detach=True)
    for line in container.logs(stream=True):
        print(line.strip())
    print('\n{} - Completed\n'.format(datetime.now()))
```

The container starts, executes and after 10 seconds prints the whole output to the terminal session:

```
$ python dockerpy.py
2019-03-18 12:18:43.508384 - Starting

b'2019-03-18 11:18:44.344516'
b'2019-03-18 11:18:45.345600'
b'2019-03-18 11:18:46.346731'
b'2019-03-18 11:18:47.347814'
b'2019-03-18 11:18:48.348900'
b'2019-03-18 11:18:49.350057'
b'2019-03-18 11:18:50.351209'
b'2019-03-18 11:18:51.352425'
b'2019-03-18 11:18:52.353539'
b'2019-03-18 11:18:53.354598'

2019-03-18 12:18:54.471805 - Completed
```

What I would like to achieve is attaching the container output to my shell and get the prints as the process occurs and not at the end when the container exits.

Comment: Try `python -u your_module.py`!

Comment: It works! Thanks!!

Comment: Maybe `stdbuf -o0 python dockerpy.py` would also work.